# Facebook send button - tracking (can be a fb bug)

Tags: facebook, api, button, send, subscribe

I trying to track sending message thru facebook 'send' button. But its not working:

```
<script>
     window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
      FB.Event.subscribe('message.send', function(response) {
          alert('!');
          console.log('test');
      });
      console.log('subscribed');
    };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=212647215514142";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

You can try it live here: http://makedreamprofits.ru/!tests/fb-send.htm

Frankly, i dont see any mistake from my side here, is it a facebook bug?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was a bug, here is link on bug tracker:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/117279138442700?browse=external_tasks_search_results_5239a8cba402f5978512754